# how to make a Relay Game via Lobby group?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity-networking, real-time-multiplayer, community-server

if something wrong, sorry! . i am a new on NETCODE multiplayer game

can u everyone tell me how to make a Relay Game with player via Lobby group?
I mean, now i know how to create lobby and relay. but i want to connect via Lobby player to Relay?
help me please!!!

can u everyone tell me how to make a Relay Game with player via Lobby group?
I mean, now i know how to create lobby and relay. but i want to connect via Lobby player to Relay?
help me please!!![this video show me only how to create lobby and relay but don't tell how to connect

Comment: "this video show me only how to create lobby and relay but don't tell how to connect", what video?